# Subspace $X \in Mat_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{R}):tr(YX)=0$, where $Y =\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 5 \\ 3 & 4 \end{bmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to prove that set of $X \in Mat_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{R}):tr(YX)=0$, where $Y =\begin{bmatrix} 
2 & 5 \\
3 & 4
\end{bmatrix}$
is subspace of space $Mat_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{R})$. But how can i find $\textbf{1}:\textbf{1} A = A\textbf{1} = A$, where A is an element of our subspace. And i also have problems with finding basis of this subspace. How can i do it?

Comment: Probably the most straightforward approach is to assume that the matrix $X$ consists of some real numbers $x_{ij}$, where $1 \leq i, j \leq 2$, calculate $YX$ explicitly and then check, under which conditions the trace of $YX$ equals $0$.

Comment: The vector space axioms don't require a multiplicative identity, just an additive identity. The zero matrix is indeed in your subspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to remember the a subspace is closed under addition and scalar multiplication, and contains the zero matrix Z.

So suppose A,B $\in$ W. That is tr(YA)=tr(YB)=0. Now consider C = A+B. We have
$$YC = Y(A+B) = YA + YB$$
So tr(YC) = tr(YA+YB) = tr(YA)+tr(YB) = 0. $\checkmark$

Now consider $k$A for any scalar k. We have Y$k$A = k(YA). 
So tr($k$YA) = $k$tr(YA) = 0.$\checkmark$

Obviously, tr(YZ) = tr(Z) = 0.$\checkmark$

Thus W is a subspace. I don't think we need to know exactly what Y is in order to show that W is a subspace.

To find a basis, consider A = $\left[\begin{array}&a &b\\c&d\end{array}\right]$. Then YA = $\left[\begin{array}&2a+5c &2b+5d\\3a+4c&3b+4d\end{array}\right]$.

Suppose A $\in$ W. Then $$tr(YA) = 2a+5c+3b+4d = 0$$ So once we pick 3 of the entires for A, the 4th will be determined. So the dimension is 3, and a possible basis would be $\left[\begin{array}&1 &0\\0&\frac{-1}{2}\end{array}\right]$,$\left[\begin{array}&0 &1\\0&\frac{-3}{4}\end{array}\right]$,$\left[\begin{array}&0 &0\\1&\frac{-5}{4}\end{array}\right]$.

Or if you scale $\left[\begin{array}&2 &0\\0&-1\end{array}\right]$,$\left[\begin{array}&0 &4\\0&-3\end{array}\right]$,$\left[\begin{array}&0 &0\\4&-5\end{array}\right]$.

Comment: thank you, but what about the basis of this subspace, how can i find it?

Comment: i'll edit my answer shortly.

Answer (score 1):

The application $\varphi : X \mapsto tr(YX)$ is linear as it is the composition of $\varphi_1 : X \mapsto YX$ and the trace applications that are both linear maps.

The set $\mathcal S$ you’re looking for is the kernel of $\varphi$ and is therefore a subspace of $Mat_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb R)$

Answer (score 1):

The map $X\mapsto\operatorname{Tr}(YX)$ is linear because it is a composition of linear maps: $X\mapsto YX$ and the trace. Your set is the kernel, so it is a subspace.

In order to find a basis of the kernel, you need to compute; if
$$
X=\begin{bmatrix} x_{11} & x_{12} \\ x_{21} & x_{22} \end{bmatrix}
$$
then
$$
YX=\begin{bmatrix}
2x_{11}+5x_{21} & 2x_{12}+5x_{22} \\
3x_{11}+4x_{21} & 3x_{12}+4x_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
so the trace is zero when
$$
2x_{11}+3x_{12}+5x_{21}+4x_{22}=0
$$
and finding a basis should be easy.